# SQL Slow nested query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a table called Staff and a table called Supervisors.

Staff has `StaffID`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, etc...

Supervisors contains `RelationshipID`, `StaffID`, `SupervisorID`, `SetBy`, `SetOn`, `Status`.

Basically, the Supervisors tables gives us an audit trail for the Staff self-relationship. We have a table of Staff, and we have a table of Staff:Staff relationships (supervisor:staff) with some extra information (obsolete, current, incorrect) and a StaffID who set it and when they set it.

Now, I'm writing a query to find all orphaned staff members. I have:

```
SELECT *
  FROM Staff
 WHERE StaffID NOT IN (SELECT StaffID
                         FROM Supervisors
                        WHERE Status = 0 
                           OR Status = 2);
```

(status 0 is initial load from corporate DB and 2 is modified record which has been verified. All others are 'obsolete', 'incorrect', etc...)

The issue is I have over 6000 staff and over 5000 staff:supervisor relationships and this is basically an NxM query meaning MySQL has to sift through 3 million permutations.

I'm not an SQL ninja, is there a better way to do this?

(Note, I do not expect to be running this particular query very often at all)

Comment: I can't image that would be very slow if you have the proper indexes in place. Set an index on `StaffId` and `Status` if you haven't already and watch your query speed drop.

Comment: @AlienWebuy it was actually timing out the 30 sec php limit but I modified the DB to have more indexes and now it's taking less than a second with OMG Ponies' query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `SUPERVISOR.staffid` and `SUPERVISOR.status` columns are ***not nullable***, use:

```
   SELECT st.*
     FROM STAFF st
LEFT JOIN SUPERVISOR s ON s.staffid = st.staffid
                      AND s.status NOT IN (0,2)
    WHERE s.staffid IS NULL
```

Otherwise, `NOT IN`/`NOT EXISTS` are equivalent & perform better if the columns are nullable.

For more info:

- http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/
- http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/

Answer (score 3):

This would be better performed as a join rather than a NOT IN:

```
SELECT st.* 
FROM Staff st
LEFT JOIN Supervisors su ON st.StaffID = su.StaffID 
          AND (su.Status <> 0 AND su.Status <> 2)
WHERE su.StaffId IS NULL
```

Here's how I transformed it:

```
NOT IN (SELECT StaffID FROM Supervisors WHERE Status = 0 OR Status = 2)
```

by applying Boole's law is equivalent to

```
IN (SELECT StaffID FROM Supervisors WHERE Status <> 0 AND Status <> 2);
```

(assuming Status can never be NULL) and from there is just a join.

Comment: Sorry, I may have been unspecific: Some staff _have no_ supervisor relationships, i.e. there is no record in the Supervisors table with the StaffID. When I run your query with my initial data (_all_ statuses are == 0), I just get the same result as my query with IN instead of NOT IN, which isn't what I need. I need to find orphaned staff.

Comment: Ozzah
: I've updated. If you accept any answer I suggest accepting OMG Ponies's answer.